How to disable Rundeck cluster mode in AWS ECS Fargate
I'm hosting Rundeck in AWS ECS Fargate - docker image v5.2.0. It runs successfully but I see in the start-up logs a Warning message:
May 28, 2024 at 17:16 (UTC+1:00)    [2024-05-28T16:16:15,238] WARN rundeckapp.BootStrap - Running in cluster mode without rundeck.primaryServerId set. Please set rundeck.primaryServerId to the UUID of the primary server in the cluster  rundeck
May 28, 2024 at 17:16 (UTC+1:00)    [2024-05-28T16:16:15,237] WARN rundeckapp.BootStrap - Cluster mode enabled, this server's UUID: a14bc3e6-75e8-4fe4-a90d-a16dcc976bf6    rundeck
May 28, 2024 at 17:16 (UTC+1:00)    [2024-05-28T16:16:15,235] INFO rundeckapp.BootStrap - loaded configuration: /home/rundeck/etc/framework.properties  rundeck

(surprisingly that UUID always remains the same, even when I change the docker image or change the number of containers from 1 to 2)
I see that the property rundeck.clusterMode.enabled=true in rundeck-config.properties file but I can't find (or there isn't one) environment variable, unlike many other configuration options in Rundeck, to set the clusterMode to false.
I also tried to look at whether ECS Fargate supports something like a postStart hook, like in k8s, but apparently, that feature has been requested (https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/952) but is not yet available.
How could I achieve this? Looking at it just from the ECS point of view, I need to modify a file in the ECS Fargate container after the ECS task runs successfully.
TIA!

Hi, are you using Process Automation (formerly "Rundeck Enterprise")?

I should've mentioned, its the Community edition.

That doesn't affect the single instance mode (it's considered a "single node cluster instance").
But if you need to set that property to false, rebuild the image using the Remco template like this answer (based on this doc entry):
In this case the rundeck-config-extra.properties will include this:
rundeck.clusterMode.enabled={{ getv("/rundeck/clusterMode/enabled", "false") }}

Build the image: docker compose build
And then, deploy it: docker compose up
So, the initialization must omit the cluster mode message:
[2024-05-28T20:57:46,408] INFO  liquibase.lockservice - Successfully released change log lock
[2024-05-28T20:57:46,560] INFO  rundeckapp.BootStrap - Starting Rundeck 5.3.0-20240520 (2024-05-20) ...
[2024-05-28T20:57:46,560] INFO  rundeckapp.BootStrap - using rdeck.base config property: /home/rundeck
[2024-05-28T20:57:46,568] INFO  rundeckapp.BootStrap - loaded configuration: /home/rundeck/etc/framework.properties
[2024-05-28T20:57:46,673] INFO  rundeckapp.BootStrap - RSS feeds disabled
[2024-05-28T20:57:46,673] INFO  rundeckapp.BootStrap - Using jaas authentication
[2024-05-28T20:57:46,675] INFO  rundeckapp.BootStrap - Preauthentication is disabled
[2024-05-28T20:57:46,702] INFO  rundeckapp.BootStrap - Rundeck is ACTIVE: executions can be run.
[2024-05-28T20:57:46,728] WARN  rundeckapp.BootStrap - [Development Mode] Usage of H2 database is recommended only for development and testing
[2024-05-28T20:57:46,755] INFO  rundeckapp.BootStrap - workflowConfigFix973: applying... 
[2024-05-28T20:57:46,760] INFO  rundeckapp.BootStrap - workflowConfigFix973: No fix was needed. Storing fix application state.
[2024-05-28T20:57:47,015] INFO  rundeckapp.BootStrap - Rundeck startup finished in 502ms
[2024-05-28T20:57:47,019] INFO  rundeckapp.Application - Started Application in 20.393 seconds (JVM running for 21.949)


Thanks for this answer. I followed the instructions and I can confirm that I do not see the cluster mode message in the logs anymore. But, if I exec into the container and look at the rundeck-config.properties file, I can still see the property rundeck.clusterMode.enabled=true. I was expecting it to be set to false. How does remco make this work?

As per the instructions here: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/docker/extending-configuration.html#special-destination-directories
Does it merge the template file rundeck-config-extra.properties into rundeck-config.properties and create a temp config file somewhere, perhaps in the memory, and use that to start Rundeck? Is it stored in the file system somewhere, maybe?

Regarding your first comment, Rundeck takes the last one. Yes, I see the rundeck.clusterMode.enabled=true line, but at the end of the file, the rundeck.clusterMode.enabled=false is there (and it's the valid configuration, which is why the message disappears when the container is launched).

Yeah, I missed the one at the bottom. Looks good, thanks again!
